# Jersey and other JAX-RS api extensions - e.g. Shiro, Guice

Tags: jersey, guice, resteasy, restlet, shiro

Does Jersey got any extensions to support frameworks like Shiro, Guice for example? Or do you use them seperately, independent from jersey?

How does it look for other JAX-RS frameworks. Restlet, RestEasy - do they provide any extensions or is it done seperately as well?

I already know that they got their own implementation of OAuth instead of cooperating with other OAuth framworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Restlet Framework, we offer an extensive set of extensions [summarized here](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/28-restlet/313-restlet.html). It is however generally easy to do your own integration with other libraries. Regarding Guice, there is already an extension in the Restlet Incubator, see [specifications here](http://wiki.restlet.org/developers/172-restlet/257-restlet/284-restlet.html).

Comment: Thats the answer I was looking for. Maybe someone can answer this for RESTEasy or Jersey too.

Answer (score 0):

The [dependency](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html) page of the Jersey docs specifies there are extensions for Guice:

> Jersey's runtime dependences are categorized into the following:
>
> Core server. The minimum set of dependences that Jersey requires for
>   the server.
>
> Core client. The minimum set of dependences that Jersey requires for
>   the client.
>
> Container. The set of container dependences. Each container provider
>   has it's own set of dependences.
>
> Entity. The set of entity dependencies. Each entity provider has it's
>   own set of dependences.
>
> Tools. The set of dependencies required for runtime tooling.
>
> Spring. The set of dependencies required for Spring.
>
> **Guice. The set of dependencies required for Guice.**

I have not tried integrating Jersey, Guice, and Shiro, but I don't see why you couldn't do it.

Comment: OK. But my question is more like: do you need an jersey supportive package to integrate shiro, guice ... or is it done by shiro, guice itself. Same for Restlet, RESTEasy and other extensions besides Shiro and Guice.